# Python regex timer improvement

Tags: python, regex, discord.py

So this is my current code for a timer in my discord.py bot..

```
#Timer (Need to option for s,m,h and exit)
@client.command()
async def timer(ctx, seconds):
    try:
       text = (seconds)
       in_seconds = {'h': 60 * 60, 'm': 60, 's': 1}
       seconds = sum(int(num) * in_seconds[weight] for num, weight in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)', text))
       if seconds > 86400:
            await ctx.send("I don't think I want you to go over 24h right now")
            raise BaseException
       if seconds < 0:
            await ctx.send("I don't think you want to do negatives")
            raise BaseException
       message = await ctx.send(f"Timer: {seconds}")
       while True:
            seconds -= 5
            if seconds < 0:
                await message.edit(content="Ended!")
                break
            await message.edit(content=f"Timer: {seconds}")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your countdown has ended!")
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send('You must enter a number!')
```

So this works perfectly when I do ??timer 10s or ??timer 5m but when I do ??timer 10 it does not automatically take it to be seconds and ends the timer immediately.. How do I fix this please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is requiring a `m`, `s` or `h`:

```
(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)
```

Change it to also allow nothing:

```
(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)?
```

and then make sure that `weight` is used or defaulted to `s`:

```
weight if weight else 's'
```

Glue it together:

```
seconds = sum(int(num) * in_seconds[weight if weight else 's'] for num, weight in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)?', text))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This was really helpful. Also if you know discord.py could you tell me how I could add a function like ??quit to stop the timer midway

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is on the regex itself:

```regex
(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)
```

Notice the token `(m|s|h)` being mandatory. Your regex will not match if there is no m, s or h in the string. We can work it around by making this optional as follows:

```regex
(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)?
```